# graph of a function with constant in denominator

Tags: calculus

graph of a function $y=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x-c}$, where $1\lt c \lt 2$.
my horizontal asymptote is at x=0, but I am stuck with vertical one, since its very depends on c, which one i don't know exactly. How should I mention it in my sketch of a graph? I also have two critical points at x=-1 and x=c. (from the derivative $$y'=-\frac{x+2+b}{2\sqrt{x+1}(x-c)^2}$$)
In the sketch c is takes as 1.1, 1.5 and 1.9.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The asymptote is $x=c$, so drawn in the vertical line $x=c$ at some sensible place on the graph and label it with an expression that depends on the variable ie "$x=c$". The drawing doesn't have to be valid for all values, just make it clear with the label that it varies with $c$.

Comment: Typo? I suppose that the $b$ in your $y'$ is $c$ .

Comment: If your function uses c as a variable as well as x, then you have a function of 2 variables $f(x,c)$. You can convert it to a function in one variable, say $f(x)$ by providing a value for 1 of them (c in this case), then it would be a special case and your graph would be valid. For each value of $c$, you would get a new vertical asymptote. This is by definition. The derivative you have shown (with respect to $x$ is suspicious!)